# Why can't I run make xv6 with make qemu, but it works fine with make qemu-nox?

Tags: makefile, qemu, xv6

I am using WSL-Ubuntu in Visual Studio Code and I have gcc, gdb, Qemu all installed and the xv6-public git cloned.
I can cd into the xv6 directory and type `make`, then `make qemu-nox` and it works just fine.

However `make qemu` doesn't work. and gives the error below. How do I get the gui for qemu working and so I don't have to use `make qemu-nox` every time?

```
qemu-system-i386 -serial mon:stdio -drive
file=fs.img,index=1,media=disk,format=raw -drive file=xv 
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
gtk initialization failed
make: *** [Makefile:226: qemu] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you don't have an X server running.

You can use [xming](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/).

Once X is running, in `bash`, just add `export DISPLAY=0:0` to help it find it.

Comment: I installed xming and the program is now running, when I do make qemu export DISPLAY=0:0. It still gives the error that gtk initialization failed.